# How to split a string with '#' in C#

Tags: c#, string, split

I tried to split a string wich contains these character #

```
domicilioSeparado = domicilio.Split(@"#".ToCharArray());
```

but every time the array contains just one member. I've tried a lot of combinations but anything seems to work, I also tried to replace the string with a blank space and it kinda works - the problem is that it remains a single string.

```
domicilio = domicilio.Replace(@"#", @" ");
```

How can I resolve this?

Complete code:

```
String[] domicilioSeparado;
String domicilio = dbRow["DOMICILIO"].ToString();

domicilioSeparado = domicilio.Split(@"#".ToCharArray());
if (Regex.IsMatch(domicilioSeparado.Last(), @"\d"))
{
    String domicilioSinNum = "";
    domicilioSinNum = domicilioSeparado[0];
    custTable.Rows.Add(counter, dbRow["CUENTA"], nombre,
        paterno, materno, domicilioSinNum, domicilioSeparado.Last(), tipoEntidad);
}
```

Comment: What's your string? The first example should work just fine. (Although `'#'` would be a lot better than `@"#".ToCharArray()`.)

Comment: Split with a '#' character should work just fine. Could you provide the input string you are using?

Comment: You realize you can simply do `domicilio.Split('#')`?

Comment: I don't suppose the characters are music sharp signs (U+266F) ♯ and not a standard number sign #?

Comment: @vcsjones: Not likely since the name [`domicilio`](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/domicilio) implies an address of some sort.

Comment: @JeffMercado: Not a lot of other ways this couldn't work.

Comment: Can you provide an example of one of the strings being split?

Comment: The input comes from a datarow, but an example would be PRIVADA#9,

Comment: Also de complete code would be:

domicilioSeparado = domicilio.Split(@"#".ToCharArray());
                            if (Regex.IsMatch(domicilioSeparado.Last(), @"\d"))
                            {
                                String domicilioSinNum = "";
                                
                                domicilioSinNum = domicilioSeparado[0];
                                
                                custTable.Rows.Add(counter, dbRow["CUENTA"], nombre, paterno, materno, domicilioSinNum, domicilioSeparado.Last(), tipoEntidad);

                            }

Comment: And the string is not splitted

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but your regex will only match a single digit, I would think you probably want `\d+`

Comment: it doesn't matter if is one or more characters ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string[] domicilioSeparado;
domicilioSeparado = domicilio.Split('#');
```

Some notes:
1 - It is ('#'), instead of ("#"); 2 - Replace does not split a string, it only replace that part, keeping as a single string.

In case you want an example that includes the printing of the whole array:

```
string domicilio = "abc#def#ghi";
string[] domicilioSeparado;
domicilioSeparado = domicilio.Split('#');
for (int i = 0; i < domicilioSeparado.Length; i++)
{
   MessageBox.Show(domicilioSeparado[i]);
}
```

It will open a Message Box for each element within domicilioSeparado.

Comment: So, I won't have an array of strings?

Comment: Yes, you will. If you print domicilioSeparado[1], for instance, you will get the second part of domicilio.

Comment: Cause I've done that, i didn't put the declaration of the string, but I think I could print domicilioSperadao[0] or domicilioSperadao[n], is it possible?

Comment: Well, then my problem isn't the split, my problem is to print just the first part of the string, insted it prints the complete string

Comment: To use it the way I told (there are other ways, of course, but I believe this is the easier way), you must declare string[] domicilioSeparado.

Comment: Yeah sure, i already have declared the string in that way, i just didn't put the line right here, but i HAve declared it

Comment: Well, I found the mistake, I was printing the whole string cause I didn't quit the last split, sorry for the troubles, thanks a lot my friend...

Comment: I'm glad to help, you're welcome. Please don't forget to chose your accepted answer (the one you considered to be most useful). Take a look at the FAQ for more details about that.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to split a string on a delimiter, in this instance '#', then you can use this:

```
domicilioSeparado = domicilio.Split("#");
```

That should give you what you want. Your second attempt simply replaces all the characters '#' in the string with ' ', which doesn't seem to be what you want. Can we see the string you're trying to split? That might help explain why it's not working.

EDIT:

Ok, here's how I think your code should look, give this a shot and let me know how it goes.

```
List<string> domicilioSeparado = new List<string>();
String domicilio = dbRow["DOMICILIO"].ToString();

domicilioSeparado = domicilio.Split("#");

if (Regex.IsMatch(domicilioSeparado.Last(), @"\d"))
{
    String domicilioSinNum = "";
    domicilioSinNum = domicilioSeparado[0];
    custTable.Rows.Add(counter, dbRow["CUENTA"], nombre,
        paterno, materno, domicilioSinNum, domicilioSeparado.Last(), tipoEntidad);
}
```

Comment: PRIVADA#9, it seems to split, because I print #9 but I cannot print PRIVADA alone

Comment: What does domcilioSeparado actually contain after that statement, though?

Comment: String domicilio = dbRow["DOMICILIO"].ToString();
                    domicilioSeparado = domicilio.Split(" ".ToCharArray());

Comment: @user1588438 The array starts at 0 buy the way.

Comment: No, set a breakpoint immediately after the statement I told you to add. Then tell me what is in domicilioSeparado when you pass PRIVADA#9 into it, please.

Comment: Ok, so domicilio = PRIVADA#9. Then you have domicilioSeparado = domicilio.Split("#");. So does domicilioSeparado = ["PRIVADA", "9"], or something else?

Comment: that's what I think, but whent I put MessageBox.Show(somicilioSeparado[0]);

Comment: it prints all the string, maybe my problem isn't the split but the printing

Comment: Did you do that immediately after the Split? I don't see why it would print the whole string. domicilioSeparado is a string array, right?

Comment: Right, sorry i didn't put the line here, but I already have it delcared

Comment: How did you declare it? I think the safest way would be to do this:

List<string> domicilioSeparado = new List<string>();

Comment: Try making it a list of strings. I don't see why this isn't working. Could you post all the code relevant to this problem?

Comment: @SeanCogan how could I add it to the principal question??

Comment: Just click the edit button under the question itself, then add it to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Cool, thank you. One idea I have is that you need to add ".ToArray()" at the end of the split, since you have domicilioSeparado defined as an array. I could be wrong, but I think split returns a list.

Comment: Updated my original answer, check it out.

Comment: Well, I found the mistake, I was printing the whole string cause I didn't quit the last split, sorry for the troubles, thanks a lot my friend...