# How to splitting special character '##' and '}'

Tags: c#, .net

I already tried [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889780/how-to-split-a-string-with-in-c-sharp) and [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889780/how-to-split-a-string-with-in-c-sharp)
still no luck.

Text1:

> Some text that contained } and again } or maybe }

Text2:

> Some text that contained ## and again ## or maybe ##

Here My code

```
string str1 = "Some text that contained } and again } or maybe }";
// Some time its contained ##

string[] words;
if (str1.Contains("}"))
{
    words = str1.Split("}");
}
else if (str1.Contains ("##"))
{
    words = str1.Split("##");
} else {
    words = null;
}
```

I got 2 error

> The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

and

> Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'           }

Comment: Double quotation marks represent strings. Single quotation marks represent characters.

Comment: Radiaku are you familiar with the Split() method..? also based on your example the code will never Split("##") where in that string is there ##

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use

```
str1.Split(new [] {"}"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

and

```
str1.Split(new [] {"##"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

of use `StringSplitOptions.None` if you want to preserve empty strings

[string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) takes input as strings only in next signatures : `Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)` and `Split(String[], Int32, StringSplitOptions)`. So at least you need to specify `StringSplitOptions` and convert one string to array of one string, Otherwise compiler doesn't know what method are you trying to invoke.

You can reduce your logic by removing one `if` statement. `Split` method doesn't throw any exceptions if it haven't found occurrence of input strings.

```
string str1 = "Some text that contained } and again } or maybe }";

string[] words;
if (str1.Contains("}") || str1.Contains ("##"))
{
    words = str1.Split(new [] {"}", "##"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

}
else
{
    words = null;
}
```

Comment: mind to explain? I still learning C# ( autodidact )

Comment: @radiaku I've added a little explanation to answer.

Comment: Why not do it all in one line
`string str1 = "Some text that contained } and again } or maybe }";
            var items = str1.Split(new string[] { "##" ,"}" },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: @DJKRAZE very nice point. I will update my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
str1.Split(new [] {"}","##"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 2):

As Dave mentioned, string split takes in only one character. If you need to split on a string, use the following code

```
string str1 = "Some text that contained } and again } or maybe }";
    // Some time its contained ##

string[] words;
if (str1.Contains("}"))
{
    words = str1.Split(new string[] { "}" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
}
else if (str1.Contains ("##"))
{
    words = str1.Split(new string[] { "##" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
} else {
    words = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to match `"##"`, [you you can pass an array of string into string.split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx)

```
tring[] separators = {"##"};
string [] sarr = mystr.Split(separators);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Note that you can use `Regex` too, so this class will let you Split by a pattern:

```
string str1 = "Some text that contained } and again } or maybe }";
// Some time its contained ##

string[] words;
if (str1.Contains("}"))
{
    words = str1.Split('}');
}
else if (str1.Contains ("##"))
{
    words = Regex.Split(str1, @"\#\#");
} else {
    words = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way [string.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7h14879.aspx) works in C#, the parameter you pass in should be a character array or a string with options. There are other overloads to the method, but those are irrelevant to your question.
Instead of using `words = str1.Split("}")`, you should use `words = str1.Split('}')` which passes in a character, not a string as the parameter.
And for the case where you need to check for a string, not a character, you should use `words = str1.Split(new string[] { "##" }, StringSplitOptions.None)` instead of `words = str1.Split("##")`.

Your final code should look like

```
string str1 = "Some text that contained } and again } or maybe }";
        // Some time its contained ##

string[] words;
if (str1.Contains("}"))
{
    words = str1.Split( ('}'));
}
else if (str1.Contains("##"))
{
    words = str1.Split(new string[] { "##" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
}
else
{
    words = null;
}
```

Check [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split) for a tutorial on how to use the Split method

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to split both strings by either } or ## you can use an array of strings that you would like to split on.

```
stringToSplit.Split(new []{"}","##"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

To see this working have a look at this Doodle [An example of how to use string.Split correctly](http://bit.ly/UCI7HQ)

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it all in one line string

```
str1 = "Some text that contained } and again } or maybe }"; 
var items = str1.Split(new string[] { "##" ,"}" },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```